# Recognize input escape sequence

Tags: bash, awk

I see that awk can recognize escape sequences

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {print "foo\nbar"}'
foo
bar
```

However, from the input it does not

```
$ awk '{print $1}' <<< 'hello\nworld'
hello\nworld
```

Can it be made to recognize escape sequences from the input?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works with variables as well

```
$ set 'hello\nworld'

$ printf %b "$1" | awk '{print $1}'
hello
world
```

Comment: Yes, which is why in my opinion your answer fails to "recognize escape sequences". The point of escape sequences is to allow any sequence to be produced. (As I said, try it. With awk, or with C, or with Python, or with bash's $'...' form.)

Comment: @StevenPenny Your question was `Can it be made to recognize escape sequences from the input?` How is using `awk's` to modify the input answering your question? May be I interpreted your question wrong?

Comment: In the general case, you would like for arbitrary lengths of backslashes to be processed correctly. `"\\"` should be interpreted as a literal backslash and `"\\\"\t\r\n"` should be backslash, double quote, tab, carriage return, newline.  I don't think this can be solved elegantly and idiomatically in Awk, but of course, a brute-force implementation isn't technically hard, just tedious.

Answer (score 3):

You need to do something like this -

```
[jaypal:~/temp] awk '{print $1}' <<< $'hello\nworld'
hello
world
```

[`bash(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/bash)

Comment: This is what I would suggest as a workaround as well, but it's not clear whether it's important to the OP to solve this particular problem (in which case I would indeed suggest to use Bash's `$'...'` string notation) or more generally to handle backslash escapes in strings in Awk.

Answer (score 0):

The here-string you're using does not expand the newline escape sequence into an actual newline. Try this:

```
`echo -e "hello\nworld" | awk '{print $1}'`
```

Or alternatively:

```
awk '{print $1}' <<< "hello
world"
```